# JAVA - Refactoring multiple "instanceof" using a List

Tags: java, list, refactoring, instanceof

At the moment I'm checking if an object is an instance of X, Y, Z and apply some methods. (These are just illustrations:)

```
if (X instanceof Car || X instaceof Bus || ...) {
   X.color = RED;
}
```

However if I have 300 objects to compare with (ex: Car, Bus, Bike, Train, Plane, ...) how would I go around factorizing it? I thought of making a List or an Array but initializing it seems a bit long:

```
Car car = new Car();
Bus bus = new Bus();
...
List<Transportation> list_t = Arrays.asList(car, bus, ...);
for (Transportation t : list_t) {
    if (X instance of t)
         X.color = RED;
}
```

Any suggestions will highly be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have lots of these kind of `if` ststements? Is there any class hierarchy, or are there no types that have subclasses?

Comment: You may want to look into Visitor-Pattern.

Comment: Why not `X.color = X.getColor();`? And then of course you can change it to simply `X.setColor();` And then you can remove it by making it so cars, busses, etc. are always red anyway.

Comment: I'll have quite a few of "if"s and the goal was just to regroup different types (ex: if instanceof ALL_TRANSPORT_USING_WHEELS, if instaceof AL_TRANSPORT_USING_WATER). I could make super classes to regroup them but if there's a way around it that'd be nice.

Comment: You don't need to create instances for your ArrayList, you can just use ClassName.class instead and use Class instead of Transportation for your list type.

Comment: Overusing `instanceof` is a sign that your code is not using object orientation correctly; you should probably use polymorphism instead (define a method in a superclass, overridde it in subclasses to do the appropriate thing for the specific subclass).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either use a common parent interface.

```
class Car implements DisplayColour {
    public Color displayColor() {
          return Color.RED;
    }
```

Or I would use a HashMap provided you know all possible classes.

```
static final Map<Class, Color> classToColorMap = new HashMap<>(); 
static {
    classToColorMap.put(Car.class, Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: I am just wondering . Can this be generalized to, given any of object returns appropriate color base on which Class. for example there is a function  . returnClassName(Object object) {returns className}  ? . I am not related to the question asker. i am just interesting about this problem .

Comment: @Optimuskck You can do `String className = object.getClass().getName();` or you can call `String className = object.getClass().getSimpleName();`

Comment: Yes . but what i ask is in your first function if i understand correct , your first function checks only for specific objects only. i mean  without hard coding for specific object can't we generalize to given any object it checks belong to specific class and returns different string ? . But i am beginning to understand i am asking a different question . i am sorry.

Comment: @Optimuskck You can generalise it by having the Class return a category like 4-wheeled-land-vehicle and you can map this category to a colour.